# elasticsearch bulk insert from s3 using lambda and python

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, bulkinsert

I have a task to delete all docs from an ElasticSearch index, and repopulate it from all the files in a S3 bucket.  I can do this singly but it is extremely slow, but doing it with bulk insert is eluding me and is just as slow.  What am I missing?  I feel that I am making the benefit of paginator's speed null and void, plus I am getting a **MemoryError** at the end when I am trying to gather all 1000 at at time and **bulk insert** it into Elasticsearch. If Bulk insert is possible, how do I do it when creating the file to insert into ES from scratch and storing it into memory. I want it to be as fast as paginator, but I am failing miserably here. What am I missing please?

I have put the data examples in the code as comments (lines 15, 38, 47-48)

```
 1  s3_bucket='s3_bucket_name'
 2  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 3  paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
 4  es_url='https://my_es_url'
 5  aws_auth=my_auth_info
 6  es_client=Elasticsearch([es_url], .....)
 7
 8  # get keys from s3 bucket
 9  for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=s3_bucket, Prefix=''):
10      if page['KeyCount']<=0 or "Contents not in page:
11          continue
12      keys= [object["Key"] for object in page["contents"]]
13      if not keys:
14          continue # nothing to see here
15      objects=[{"Key":key"} for key in keys]     # [{'key': 'path/filename1_02032022T000007Z.json'}, etc...]
16      # paginator maxes out at 1000, so the number of keys in objects are 1000 at a time (total count > 100,000)
17      count = len(objects)
18      total +=count
19      if dryrun:
20          print("dryrun: {0} objects".format(count))  # 1000
21          print("{0} total objects".format(total))    # 102701 total objects
22      else
23          es_index='es_index_name'
24          # delete docs from ES index
25          es_client.delete_by_query(index=es_index, body={"query":{"match_all":{}}})
26  
27          # copy form s3 to ES     ##really slow after this because getting data one at a time
28          actions=[]  #list
29          index={}  #dict
30          index[_index']=es_index
31          doc={}
32          for obj in objects:
33              key_id=obj['Key']
34              id.partition('.json')[0]
35              index['_id']=id        # {'_index': 'es_index_name', '_id': 'filename'}
36              # get object body
37              data_obj = s3.Object(s3_bucket,key_id)
38              data_json=data_obj.get()  # {'data1':'value1','data2':'value2','data3':'value3'}
39              data_json=data_json.get('Body').read().decode('utf-8')
40              data_json=data_json.replace("'",'"')  
41              doc=data_string
42              doc['id']=id
43              actions.append(index)
44              actions+=str(actions)+'\n'
45              actions+=str(doc)+'\n'      # GETTING MEMORYERROR HERE
46              # actions:
47              # [{'_index':'es_index_name','_id':'filename1_02032022T000007Z'},
48              # {'data1':'value1','data2':'value2','data3':'value3'}]
49      print('--------------------------------')
50      response=helpers.bulk(es_client,actions)
51      print('Data successfully inserted into ES')
52      print("PROCESS_ALL: {0} objects".format(count))  # 1000
53      print("{0} total objects".format(total))    # 102701 total objects
```

Comment: Increase your Lambda function's configured RAM significantly. That will also cause it to run faster. I'd also recommend bulk inserting no more than N documents in a single bulk insert. Try 20, 50, 100 at a time. That will also help with your out of memory issue (if you code it correctly).

Comment: It's weird in my company's version of Cloud9 it works in Python, although still slow.  When I bring it to Lambda and max out the time to 15 and max out the memory used, it times out and doesn't work, even if I bring the number down to 5.  This may have to turn into a command line python application to run as needed, vs doing it with CloudWatch Rules.

Comment: If your Lambda function times out at 15 mins then that is likely to be because there is no viable network path from the Lambda function to the Elasticsearch cluster. Assuming the ES cluster is in private subnet of your VPC then the Lambda function should also be in a private subnet of the same VPC and it should be configured with a security group that is allowed network ingress to the ES cluster.

Comment: No, it is because it is taking too long.  I can create code to insert them 1 at a time and that works, it is just when I create code to do bulk insert it times out when implemented in Lambda.

Comment: Apologies, I assumed that when you said you brought the number down to 5 that that was something that should almost definitely succeed within 15 minutes, hence I assumed connectivity issue. Did you test this with high RAM configuration? That improves runtime performance and network bandwidth.

Comment: I put timeout time to 15 minutes, the max, and the ram to the max available, 10240MB.